# How do duplicate/clone ActiveRecord::Relation in optimized way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to clone a list of `ActiveRecord` objects in an optimized way. Maybe the way that I am using is optimized already but I need to speed up this process. So this is my code

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  data = MyModel.where(column_1: 'x')
  data.each do |item|
    new_item = item.dup
    new_item.column_2 = 'y'
    new_item.save!
  end
end
```

Maybe there is a better way of duplicating a list of records at once then update all of them with one query. I tried to Google it but no luck till now.

Comment: You could use a gem like `bulk_insert` https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert to do multiple inserts in one single SQL query.

Comment: @arieljuod can I use to duplicate a list of objects? or it has to be manual creating then use it to commit all of these records in one insert query.

Comment: You can use your `data.each` loop to create an array of hashes with the values to insert instead of using dup/save. Then after the loop you'll have a big array with all the data you want to reinsert. And then you call `bulk_insert` with all the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is to use `single insert statement` instead of `multiple inserts` even though if it's in one DB `transaction`.

And [bulk_insert](https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert) gem will help you to do it. ( Thanks to [arieljuod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1430810/arieljuod) )

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right, you want to duplicate objects that meet condition

```
(column_1: 'x')
```

You can try this approach, looks like it will do the same

```
MyModel.where(column_1: 'x').find_each { |u| u.dup.update(column2: 'y') }
```

But a little slower(benchmarked n = 1000)

```
<Benchmark::Tms:0x00007f96e6a1b970 @label="**dup.update**", @real=6.75463099999979, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.331546, @utime=2.2468139999999996, @total=2.5783599999999995>,

<Benchmark::Tms:0x00007f96e8cb23f8 @label="**dup.save!**", @real=6.470054999999775, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.32828900000000005, @utime=1.972385, @total=2.300674>
```

Comment: But this approach is executing an insert statement for every record which will make it slow.

Comment: Yes, same as yours( looks like `bulk_insert ` is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this as quickly as possible then SQL is the way to go.

Something like this would do it:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<-SQL
   INSERT INTO my_models (column_1, column_2, column_3, ..)
      SELECT column_1, 'y', column_3, ..
      FROM my_models WHERE column_1 = 'x';
SQL
```

This should work in PostgreSQL and MySql.

If you have any rails magic columns (created_at, updated_at etc) they will have to be added manually in the SQL.